# How to replace text in Word with Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba, text, replace, ms-word

I am trying to send an email using a Word template with VBA. In the middle of the template I added << Table >> as text. I would like to replace this text with a table in an Excel file.

I receive

> Run-Time error '13'

when it comes to

```
.Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Range("A24:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

```vb
Sub SendMail()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim olm As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    Set ol = New Outlook.Application

    Set olm = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\campoalv\Desktop\US-Dec.docx")

    lr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With wd.Selection.Find
        .Text = "<<Table>>"
        .Replacement.Text = Sheet1.Range("A24:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    doc.Content.Copy
    
    With olm
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "Test"
    
        Set Editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Editor.Content.Paste
        '.Send
    End With

    Set olm = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set doc = Nothing
    wd.Quit
    Set wd = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A24:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will return an array. `.Replacement.Text` expects a `String`. I don't think you want a find/replace here, maybe a copy/paste.

Comment: May i ask you how would you do it?

Comment: You'll need to build the table in Word from the (visible) range value.  Maybe start with something like this: https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-add-table-and-fill-data-to-the-word-document/

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the range into the Word document where it finds the content `<<Table>>`. Something like this...

```
Sub SendMail()
On Error GoTo Err_
    Dim Word      As Word.Application
    Dim Document  As Word.Document
    
    Set Word = New Word.Application
    Set Document = Word.Documents.Add("C:\Users\campoalv\Desktop\US-Dec.docx")
    
    With Document.Content
        If .Find.Execute("<<Table>>") Then
            Range("A24:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            .Paste
        End If
    End With
    
    With New Outlook.Application
        With .CreateItem(olMailItem)
            .To = ""
            .Subject = "Test"
            
            With .GetInspector.WordEditor
                Document.Content.Copy
                .Content.Paste
            End With
            
            .Display
        End With
    End With
    
    Word.Quit 0
    
Exit_:
    Exit Sub
Err_:
    If Not Word Is Nothing Then
        If Not Word.Visible Then Word.Quit 0
    End If

    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume Exit_
End Sub
```